# express js calling get routes from in application

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to be able to call a chain of middle ware as if it was being hit by an http request with out having to make an actual request.

Basically I have some get logic that I would like to reuse internally from the command line and would like a simple way to create a faux request and be able to call route chains as regular javascript methods.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use [supertest](https://npmjs.org/package/supertest) to do this.